# Recommendations for dobro instruction books

Tags: guitar, technique, practice, learning, acoustic-guitar

I’m a mostly self taught, intermediate guitar player. I recently started playing dobro in open G tuning and love it. I’m looking for recommendations for instruction books. I want to learn harmonized scales, slants and chords. Something that has tablature for some simple songs would be great too. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SE MPT! Questions about recommendations are off-topic here so this is likely to get closed. Please have a look at the [help center](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) to know what questions would be a better fit here!